# Postgres 11 setting for Debezium CDC connector

Tags: postgresql, cdc, debezium

can you pls let me know what should be the exact configuration required in postgres11 for Debezium CDC connector. I have made the modification in postgresql.conf file the wall_level to logical. While changing in pb_hba.conf file, and trying to restart the postgres service, it's became corrupt and need the reinstallation of it. So can any one pls let me know what exact changes needs to be done for running the debezium CDC in postgres 11.

Regards
Sanjaya

Comment: What isn't clear from https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/postgresql.html#server-configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make these changes to `postgres.conf` (to use the native `pgoutput` plugin):

```
wal_level = logical         # minimal, replica, or logical
max_wal_senders = 1         # max number of walsender processes
max_replication_slots = 1   # max number of replication slots
```

More details in [the great docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/postgresql.html#server-configuration).

Comment: @user3897707 is it useful for you?